# WPF XamComboEditor/ComboEditorTool - Setting default text

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I'm trying to add some default text to combo boxes that will show when there is no item selected.  I'm using a style to acheive this which works great when the combo is first loaded.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igRibbon:ComboEditorTool}" x:Key="PleaseSelect">
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
<Setter Property="Text" Value="Please Select" />
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<igRibbon:ComboEditorTool Style="{StaticResource PleaseSelect}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem }" />
```

But when the combo's selected item is reset (by setting it to null, which sets the SelectedIndex to -1) it fails to display the default text (even though the the trigger does fire), what could be the reason for this? Is there a better way to reset the selected item?

Cheers

Here is the solution that I used, thanks to @AlexPaven for the idea:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return "Please Select";
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string && ((string)value) == "Please Select")
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Infragistics suite, but I suspect it's the same thing as with regular combo boxes: since you have a binding on SelectedItem, the Text cannot be set to an item that blatantly disobeys that binding; the Text IS a representation of the SelectedItem. If the SelectedItem is null, then the Text must also be a representation of null.

I'm guessing (didn't try it and I may be just plain wrong) you could probably accomplish this with an IValueConverter that returns a custom string when the passed object is null (and returns the object unchanged otherwise), set on the SelectedItem binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the following Converter but it doesn't work:
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "Please Select";
            else
                return value;
        }

The combo doesn't display anything.

Comment: After looking at this again, the converter idea works. I'll add the code as a separate answer so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but let me answer it with a more Infragistics related answer.

---

***Let's start with a short side node:**

We have to be careful when using `XamComboEditor` without specifying the namespace,
because in the Infragistics Framework the class is defined two times.*

*1. [`Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamComboEditor`](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.editors~infragistics.windows.editors.xamcomboeditor)*
 *2. [`Infragistics.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor`](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.editors.xamcomboeditor~infragistics.controls.editors.xamcomboeditor)*

*Referring to the Infragistics Help, the recommended one is the **`Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamComboEditor`***

> See the [About xamComboEditor:](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/wpf-xamcomboeditor-about-xamcomboeditor)
>
> *We recommend that you use the xamComboEditor control instead of the xamComboEditor (Input) control. The xamComboEditor (Input) is being planned for retirement over the next few years and will not receive any new features.*

---

**And now to your question:**
Both, the `Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamComboEditor` and the derived [`Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.ComboEditorTool`](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.ribbon~infragistics.windows.ribbon.comboeditortool), have a property for setting a default text for null values. This property is called:

> **NullText**
>   *The text to display when the value of the editor is null and the editor is not in edit mode. The default value is empty string. (Inherited from Infragistics.Windows.Editors.TextEditorBase)*

---

Also the `Infragistics.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor` provides such a property. It is called:

> **EmptyText**
>   Gets/Sets the Text that should be displayed when the editor doesn't have anything selected. (Inherited from Infragistics.Controls.Editors.ComboEditorBase)

---

**Example for `ComboEditorTool`:**

Referencing the following dlls:

- InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v18.1
- InfragisticsWPF4.Ribbon.v18.1
- InfragisticsWPF4.v18.1

xaml-Snippet:

```
xmlns:ribbon="http://infragistics.com/Ribbon"

...

<ribbon:ComboEditorTool Id="SampleComboEditorTool"
                        NullText="Select ..."
                        ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                        />
```

Screenshot:
[image: Result CTE]

---

**Example for `Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamComboEditor`:**

Referencing the following dlls:

- InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v18.1
- InfragisticsWPF4.v18.1

xaml-Snippet:

```
xmlns:editors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"

...

<editors:XamComboEditor Width="120" Height="23"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        NullText="Select ..."
                        />
```

Screenshot:
[image: Result I.W.E.XCE]

---

**Example for `Infragistics.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor`:**

Referencing the following dlls:

- InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Editors.XamComboEditor.v18.1
- InfragisticsWPF4.v18.1

xaml-Snippet:

```
xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"

...

<ig:XamComboEditor Width="120" Height="23" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                   EmptyText="Select ..."
                   />
```

Screenshot:
[image: Result I.C.E.XCE]

---

*Second side note: the first occurrence I've found for the property NullText was in the Help Doc of Version 2012.1. [See here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Ribbon.v12.1~Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.ComboEditorTool_members.html)*